# MySQL: Selecting something different if select doesnt return any rows

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT timestamp FROM table WHERE id = '10'
```

Is it possible to get the SELECT above to return a timestamp of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' if there is no id of '10' in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes...

Use an If Exist / else statement. Your else can return the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a select for it, instead of handling it with if-else or from php/etc, the following trick should work:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.timestamp,t2.tst_hack) timestamp
FROM table t1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 10 as id, '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as tst_hack) t2 ON t1.id=t2.id;
```

(just note that it is really hacking, so you should have a good reason for it)

[update]

If there is a matching id and its timestamp is NULL, `COALESCE` will overwrite it to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' too. If it is a problem and it is important to keep the NULL value, then `IF(t1.id IS NULL, t2.tst_hack, t1.timestamp)` works better than `COALESCE`.

Comment: Hooray for RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQLi :

```
<?php 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT timestamp FROM table WHERE id = 10");

/* determine number of rows result set */
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($row_cnt == 0) {

  echo '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

  //or store as a variable to use else where.

  $my_result = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

} else {

  // else if there are results, do something ... 

}
```